# There is an issue with the Apache Felix SCR implementation of OSGi DS

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, declarative-services

The [OSGi DS Specification](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/8.1.0/service.component.html#service.component-delayed.component) mentions :

> When the service is requested, if the service has the `scope` attribute set to `bundle`, SCR must create and activate a unique component configuration for each bundle requesting the service.

In other words, if a component specifies a service with `bundle` scope, and this service is requested by two different bundles at the same time, then you call the method `org.osgi.service.component.runtime.ServiceComponentRuntime.getComponentConfigurationDTOs(ComponentDescriptionDTO)`, you should get **two** different `ComponentConfigurationDTO`.

But based on the Apache Felix implementation `org.apache.felix.scr_2.2.6.jar`, you can only get **one** `ComponentConfigurationDTO`.

I checked the source code and it uses class `org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceFactoryComponentManager` to manage such component and its field `serviceContexts` to maintain all the component instances under that component :

```java
// maintain the map of ComponentContext objects created for the
// service instances
private IdentityHashMap<S, ComponentContextImpl<S>> serviceContexts = new IdentityHashMap<>();
```

Such a code implementation, which makes a single component configuration associated with multiple component instances, it is also inconsistent with the  [specification](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/8.1.0/service.component.html#d0e27474) ：

> Component Instance - An instance of the component implementation class. A component instance is created when a component configuration is activated and discarded when the component configuration is deactivated. A component instance is associated with exactly one component configuration.

Comment: By the way, how do I report this issue to Apache, there is no "issues" or "discussions" portal in github https://github.com/apache/felix-dev/tree/master/scr/.

Comment: Apache uses Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/FELIX